# как работать с txt с помощью jquery

Tags: jquery

здраствуйте! имеется переменная, так же имеется файл isnotvalue.txt с множеством числовых и буквенных выражений которые недопустимы в переменной в формате:
9eHJ
BlKo7
итд
задача заключается в том чтобы проверить переменную на на наличие недопустимых значений
рекомендовали решение но ничего не понятно

```js
var YOUR_VARIABLE = 2;

$.get('isnotvalue.txt', data => {
   const linesArray = data.split('\n').map(i => Number(i));
    console.log(linesArray.includes(YOUR_VARIABLE))
}, 'text');
```

Comment: А чем не устраивает делать к примеру все проверки на сервере, а на клиент выводить лишь ответ - в виде допустимо или нет? Ибо клиенту доверять нельзя.

Comment: простите, а это как? я просто программист 2 месяца)

Comment: Если более конкретно то у меня генератор паролей, собстна переменная - это пароль, а текстовик это список того чего в пароле быть не должно, как это реализовать - у меня просто голова дыбом...

Comment: генератор паролей для конкретной  организациии, и соотвестственно текстовик с запрещенными значениями у них свой

Comment: @MichaelVaysman [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема вероятно в том, что ничего непонятно, вероятно это потому, что тот кто вам рекомендовал решил сделать рекомендацию на EcmaScript6, перепишем на EcmaScript5, поправим ошибки:

```
var linesArray = [];

//файл с невалидными значениями незачем загружать несколько раз - вынесу отдельно функцию testValidity - её можно использовать сколько угодно
//НО только после того как файл загрузится и заполнится linesArray 
jQuery.get('isnotvalue.txt', function(data) {//заменяем стрелочную на стандартное объявление функции
    linesArray = data.split(/\s+/);//я так понял у вас запрещённые значения не только числовые, и могут быть разделены пробелами

    testValidity(123);//тестим число
    testValidity('9eHJ');//тестим строку
}, 'text');

var testValidity = function(value){
  value = typeof value != 'string' ? value.toString() : value;//приведение типов к строковому
  var isInvalid = linesArray.indexOf(value)!=-1;//это эквивалентно вызову .includes(value), только includes ещё нет в ES5
  alert(value + (isInvalid ? ' не валидно :(' : 'валидно!'));
  return !isInvalid;// функция вернёт true, если значение допустимо, false иначе
};
```

Comment: спасибо большое за ответ)) а можно реализовать тест не на одну строку, а на весь массив? т.е допустим если значений в txt допустим 100 то чтобы проверить на все 100 значений?

Comment: testValidity(linesArray); ? так будет работать?

Comment: `если значений в txt допустим 100 то чтобы проверить на все 100 значений` так и есть проверяется точное совпадение по всему массиву